# Editing ggplot2 Bubble Plot in R: Size, colors, and labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, frequency

I am trying to do a few things with this bubble plot.

1. I'd like to add a label for the frequency of occurences in each bubble on my plot
2. Change the color scheme and theme of this graph, including the sizes of the bubbles (after adding in after_stat, I was unable to add this in. after_stat seems to be what is allowing me to chart frequencies in color and size)
3. Change the title of the legend from "n" to anything else.

```
p<-ggplot(Dataframe, aes(x = Confidence, y = Knowledge)) + geom_count(aes(color = after_stat(n), size=after_stat(n))) +guides(color = 'legend') + labs(x="Confidence", y="Knowledge") + theme(axis.title = element_text(size = (15), colour = "black"), 
  axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = (12)))
```

[image]

---

Previously, I tried this:

I was only able to make the bubbles one color (but whatever color I wanted-just not more than 1), but the bubbles could be made bigger:

```
p<-ggplot(Dataframe, aes(x = Confidence, y = Knowledge)) + geom_count(color="blue") + scale_size(range= c(1,20), name = "Co-occurring")+ labs(x="Confidence", y="Knowledge") + theme(axis.title = element_text(size = (15), colour = "black"), 
  axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = (12)))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include the output of running `dput(Dataframe)` so we don't have to make our own data and hope it has the same characteristics as yours?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not able to share the data at this time. However, I replicated these graphs using Likert data from Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/arslanali4343/top-personality-dataset/data

If you wanted to try with this dataset, I think it would produce similar results.

Comment: Fake is fine. If your question is about plotting, you'll get better responses faster if you can provide some data so people can skip to that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add count labels with `geom_text` using `stat = "sum"` The size of the bubbles is changed with the `range` argument of `scale_size_continuous`. For a labeled bubble chart, I would tend to use `shape = 21` for the bubbles and control their color with the fill aesthetic. This can be specified with whatever colors you choose using `scale_fill_gradientn`. To get the name on the legend changed, add the same name as the first argument to the fill and size scales.

As an aside, the order of the items on the x axis and y axis are wrong. You need to fix this by converting Knowledge and Confidence to factors with the correct levels:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Dataframe %>%
  mutate(across(any_of(c("Confidence", "Knowledge")), 
                ~ factor(.x, c("Not at all", "A little", "Somewhat",
                               "Very", "Extremely")))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Confidence, y = Knowledge)) + 
  geom_count(aes(fill = after_stat(n), size = after_stat(n)), shape = 21) +
  geom_text(stat = "sum", aes(label = after_stat(n)), size = 5) +
  scale_fill_gradientn("Observations", guide = "legend",
                       colors = c("pink", "white", "lightblue")) +
  scale_size_continuous("Observations", range = c(6, 15)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 5 * .pt)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Without reproducible data, I have had to construct a random data set with the same names and essential structure as your own:

```r
set.seed(123)

Dataframe <- data.frame(Confidence = sample(c("A little",
                                              "Somewhat",
                                              "Very",
                                              "Extremely"), 100, TRUE),
                        Knowledge  = sample(c("Not at all", 
                                              "A little",
                                              "Somewhat",
                                              "Very",
                                              "Extremely"), 100, TRUE))
```