# change fill color of continuous bubbleplot ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, bubble-chart

I want to change the colors of the bubbles in the plot

```
ggplot(sum_length, 
       aes(x=vb_width, y=slope, size = length)) +
    geom_point(alpha=0.5)+
   theme_classic() +
  ylab("Slope category (%)") +
  xlab("Valley bottom width (m)") +
  scale_y_discrete(labels= slopebins)+
  scale_size(range = c(.1, 12), name="Amount of occupied\n habitat (km)")
```

So, I would like each size to also be a different color, on the viridis palette if possible. I cannot use this solution because the size value is continuous for my data and for the example their data are discrete: [Editing ggplot2 Bubble Plot in R: Size, colors, and labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77190634/editing-ggplot2-bubble-plot-in-r-size-colors-and-labels)

Data:

```
  slope vb_width MU      length
1   1to3     <35m 21  26.0568635
2  3to10     <35m 21 133.8732929
3   gt10     <35m 21  49.9302440
4    lt1     <35m 21  13.6335112
5   1to3 >285-427 21   9.5806268
6  3to10 >285-427 21   0.3888544
7   gt10 >285-427 21   0.0000000
8    lt1 >285-427 21  24.3259779
9   1to3   >35-70 21  66.0737107
10 3to10   >35-70 21 140.3568265
11  gt10   >35-70 21  23.9712848
12   lt1   >35-70 21  42.4018746
13  1to3     >427 21   9.0315019
14 3to10     >427 21   0.3993908
15  gt10     >427 21   0.0000000
16   lt1     >427 21 163.8209682
17  1to3  >70-285 21  72.3702302
18 3to10  >70-285 21  38.4964008
19  gt10  >70-285 21   7.9305055
20   lt1  >70-285 21  85.7479024
```

Comment: `aes([what you have], color = length))` + `scale_color_viridis_c()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some minor tweaks:

- add a variable for the `fill` aesthetic (add `fill = length`)
- change the shape in `geom_point()` to one that can be filled (add `shape = 21`)
- add `scale_fill_viridis_c()` to change the color of the bubbles to the viridis palette

E.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "  slope vb_width MU      length
1   1to3     <35m 21  26.0568635
2  3to10     <35m 21 133.8732929
3   gt10     <35m 21  49.9302440
4    lt1     <35m 21  13.6335112
5   1to3 >285-427 21   9.5806268
6  3to10 >285-427 21   0.3888544
7   gt10 >285-427 21   0.0000000
8    lt1 >285-427 21  24.3259779
9   1to3   >35-70 21  66.0737107
10 3to10   >35-70 21 140.3568265
11  gt10   >35-70 21  23.9712848
12   lt1   >35-70 21  42.4018746
13  1to3     >427 21   9.0315019
14 3to10     >427 21   0.3993908
15  gt10     >427 21   0.0000000
16   lt1     >427 21 163.8209682
17  1to3  >70-285 21  72.3702302
18 3to10  >70-285 21  38.4964008
19  gt10  >70-285 21   7.9305055
20   lt1  >70-285 21  85.7479024
", header = TRUE)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=vb_width, y=slope, size = length, fill = length)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5, shape = 21)+
  theme_classic() +
  ylab("Slope category (%)") +
  xlab("Valley bottom width (m)") +
  #scale_y_discrete(labels=slopebins)+
  scale_size(range = c(.1, 12), name="Amount of occupied\n habitat (km)") +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

EDIT: To combine the legends you need to make them the same 'type' (guide_legend) and they need the same name, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "  slope vb_width MU      length
1   1to3     <35m 21  26.0568635
2  3to10     <35m 21 133.8732929
3   gt10     <35m 21  49.9302440
4    lt1     <35m 21  13.6335112
5   1to3 >285-427 21   9.5806268
6  3to10 >285-427 21   0.3888544
7   gt10 >285-427 21   0.0000000
8    lt1 >285-427 21  24.3259779
9   1to3   >35-70 21  66.0737107
10 3to10   >35-70 21 140.3568265
11  gt10   >35-70 21  23.9712848
12   lt1   >35-70 21  42.4018746
13  1to3     >427 21   9.0315019
14 3to10     >427 21   0.3993908
15  gt10     >427 21   0.0000000
16   lt1     >427 21 163.8209682
17  1to3  >70-285 21  72.3702302
18 3to10  >70-285 21  38.4964008
19  gt10  >70-285 21   7.9305055
20   lt1  >70-285 21  85.7479024
", header = TRUE)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=vb_width, y=slope, size = length, fill = length)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5, shape = 21)+
  theme_classic() +
  ylab("Slope category (%)") +
  xlab("Valley bottom width (m)") +
  #scale_y_discrete(labels=slopebins)+
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(.1, 12), name="Amount of occupied\n habitat (km)",
                        guide = guide_legend()) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Amount of occupied\n habitat (km)",
                       guide = guide_legend())
```

[image]

Or with `guide_bins()`:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=vb_width, y=slope, size = length, fill = length)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5, shape = 21)+
  theme_classic() +
  ylab("Slope category (%)") +
  xlab("Valley bottom width (m)") +
  #scale_y_discrete(labels=slopebins)+
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(.1, 12), name="Amount of occupied\n habitat (km)",
                        guide = guide_bins()) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Amount of occupied\n habitat (km)",
                       guide = guide_bins())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is very close. How would you then color the legend circles to be the appropriate color based on the size as well?

Comment: and completely remove the color legend?

Comment: Yep - I think I understand what you want - I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: Perfect, perfect! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome; thanks for including all the required information and the link to the 'almost works' post @vermicellion